# When can Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) not belong to the %USERPROFILE% folder?

Tags: .net, special-folders

Environment: Windows PC running .NET Framework.
Sample code:

```
Console.WriteLine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal)  
Console.Readline()
```

On my PC, this results in c:\Users\mds\Documents.  Doing an echo %USERPROFILE% at the command line yields c:\Users\mds.

My customer's environment is more complicated, involving redirection and roaming profiles.  The above code shows \\someserver\users\theiruser.  Doing an echo %USERPROFILE% shows c:\Users\theiruser.

Theiruser was migrated to the server \\anotherserver, but the above code still shows \\someserver\users\theiruser.  They allege it should either come back with \\anotherserver\users\theiruser, or c:\Users\theiruser\Documents.

Am I executing the wrong code to obtain the Personal (or MyDocuments) folder, or have they configured something wrong (and if so, what)?

Comment: This is entirely in control of the user's IT staff, nothing you can do about it.  They should ask a question about it at serverfault.com

Comment: `Environment.GetFolderPath` internally uses the shell32.dll function `SHGetFolderPath` - which is the proper function to use.  So I would lean towards a misconfigured environment.